# Pass an ID from Ajax to a Django view

Tags: django, ajax

I have a Django view that accepts an ID and returns a Json Response. Now on Ajax, I want to call the django view with an ID.

Here is my AJAX:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#button").click(function () {
    var id = 25;
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",  # Added here. Now error message changed
      url: "/account/check_id/" 
      data: {
        id: id,
      },
      dataType: "json",
      success: function (data) {
        if (data.is_taken) {
          alert("ID is available");
        }
      },
    });
  });
});
```

Additional Data:

url:

```
path('check_id/<int:id>/', hrViews.check_id, name='check_id'),
```

view:

```
def check_id(request, id, *args, **kwargs):
```

However, when I click on button, I get error message

`GET http://localhost:8000/account/check_id/?id=25 404 (Not Found)`. The `?id=` is causing the error. How to remove it?

**EDIT**
After adding type: "POST", got message

```
POST http://localhost:8000/account/check_id/
```

How to pass ID here?

Note. Based on w3schools, the data{} is used to pass information to server. So I think that I should pass my ID here. However, my url does not get the ID from data. Please correct me on this if my assumption is wrong.

Comment: The `?id=` is a get parameter. 1) The url before this did not match. 2) There is no object with id 25. Looking at your url the id should be **in** the url (case 1 here) and not as a get parameter.

Comment: Noted on the get param. Added a `type: "POST",` on my Ajax call. Now it is saying POST http....check_id/ how should I pass an ID here?

Comment: The id is supposed to go like this `http://localhost:8000/account/check_id/25/`

Comment: What is pre and code. sorry still noob here.

Comment: You write `var id = 25;` do you always want to be getting only id 25? Or do you have some button which when pressed would get the correct id? Render the correct url you need as a data-attribute in some relevant tag (instead of hardcoding it in javascript).

Comment: The var id = 25 is just for example. I have other code to get the id based on input value. This is just for simplicity's sake.

Answer (score 0):

So I made some changes and this is what worked for me.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#hold").click(function () {
    var id = 25;
    $.ajax({
      url: "/account/check_id/" + id,
      dataType: "json",
      success: function (data) {
        if (data.is_taken) {
          alert("ID is available");
        }
      },
    });
  });
});
```

Removed the type: "POST", then concatinate on URL with my ID. It works so I will go with this based on my use case.

Comment: `"/account/check_id/" + id + "/"` would be better (would prevent any extra redirects, which currently django must be doing). In fact there is a better way in some tag add an attribute like `data-url="{% url 'check_id' <some_variable_with_id_here> %}"` and get that url using JavaScript.

Comment: Yeah I tried the {%%} thing but it returns alphanumeric instead so I used file path instead. Will add the "/". Thanks.